# Set auto-fill in markdown mode, but exclude code block headers

Tags: markdown-mode, auto-fill-mode

I want to use `auto-fill-mode` in Markdown files. By default, it works fine, with one exception. I'm using the [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) variant of markdown. This requires that code block headers remain on one line. They are frequently much longer than my fill-column, so if I use `auto-fill`, they get wrapped. How can I exclude these lines from getting filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto-fill-mode` refers to the variable `auto-fill-function` to determine how to fill lines. `auto-fill-function` is always a local variable, making it easy to define your own function for any mode you like. To solve my own problem, I use the following:

````el
(defun tws-markdown-auto-fill ()
  (auto-fill-mode)
  (setq auto-fill-function 'tws-markdown-fill-function))

(defun tws-markdown-fill-function ()
  (unless
      (save-excursion
        (beginning-of-line)
        (looking-at "```{"))
    (do-auto-fill)))

(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook 'tws-markdown-auto-fill)
````